# Asymptotic formula for restricted partition function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, asymptotics, partitions

Let $p(n)$ be the [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29). Hardy and Ramanujan - and Uspensky, independently proved the asymptotic formula
$$(1) \quad p(n) \sim \frac1{4\sqrt{3}} \frac{e^{c_0\sqrt{n}}}{n} \text{ as } n \to +\infty ,$$
where $c_0 := \pi \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$. In *Nathanson - Elementary Methods in Number Theory* we have the following

**Theorem 16.1** If $A$ is a set of positive integers with [natural density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) $\alpha > 0$ and $\gcd(A) = 1$, then the restricted partition function $p_A(n)$ (i.e., as $p(n)$ but only the partitions whose all elements belong to $A$ are counted) satisfied
$$(2)\quad \log p_A(n) \sim c_0\sqrt{\alpha n} \text{ as } n \to +\infty .$$

Unfortunately, from (2) we can't get an asymptotic formula for $p_A(n)$ similar to (1), but only the weaker
$$\quad p_A(n) = e^{c_0\sqrt{\alpha n} (1 + o(1))} \text{ as } n \to +\infty .$$

So my questions are: Is it true that (under the hypothesis of Theorem 16.1) we have
$$ p_A(n) \sim C_A \frac{e^{c_0\sqrt{\alpha n}}}{n} \text{ as } n \to +\infty,$$
for some $C_A > 0$ ? If not, are there some other asymptotic formula for $p_A(n)$ ?

Thank you in advance for any references/suggestions.

Comment: The existence of density is an extremely weak assumption. Indeed, suppose that something like you said were true. Add just one number $a$ to $A$. Then the number of new partitions of $n$ is $Q(n)=P(n)+P(n-a)+P(n-2a)+\dots$ and you can see that $C_A$ (if it was there for $A$) now becomes a growing function in $n$ (any finite number of terms would be of the same order of magnitude if your conjecture were anywhere close to the truth). Adding a sequence of numbers of $0$ uniform density results in a total havoc showing that you do not have any chance to change $o(1)$ to anything explicit.

Comment: To get the last statement immediately and without any computation, just look at it by the eyes of asymptotics (that has to kick in somewhere) and ask yourself how you can possibly know by the moment you decide to board the train and start making accurate predictions whether the density is not going to change somewhere far beyond that point.

Comment: The moral is, of course, not that you cannot compute the number of partition with small relative error quickly, just that you need to consider some quantities other than density when doing so. So, the answer to your last question is still "most likely, yes" though I have no time now to attempt a computation. I put this remark separately because I thought it was obvious, but then I looked at my second one, at your question, and thought again :-)